# difference between two exceptions

Tags: java

I have a task to predict output of the program without printing it.

In this program person did not overwritte toString() method and variant of output

```
 Exception in thread "main" 
 java.lang.MethodNotFoundException
```

and the second one is

```
 cannot resolve symbol 
 symbol: method toString ()
```

What is difference between these 2?

Comment: **Please show us your _code_.**

Comment: A trick, neither of these will happen, toString() is defined for all java Objects.

Comment: use the homework tag if this is a homework question

Comment: thank you everybody for the answers!=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former is a runtime exception, the second is a compile an error that won't allow your code to run in the first place.  Neither of these should come up if you run a toString method without overriding it unless you define an explicit class hierarchy in which you have a class throwing the former exception then have one of its children fail to override it.

Answer (score 0):

First appears in runtime where dynamically a method existence is tested and it does not exists.

The second one is at compile time becuase a method doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd exception is a Checked Exception, which can be caught and handled in your application and if in case you do not catch your 2nd type of exception, the compiler will throw an error during compiling.

while The 1st exception is an Unchecked Exception. it cannot be detected by the compiler during compilation and you cannot catch it. better call it Devil Exception :)